# How to obtain the current WiFi eduroam account information on Samsung Galaxy?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I'm using a WiFi eduroam connection on my Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra (One UI 5.1 / Android 13). I can connect to eduroam via 2 accounts, and I don't remember which one I'm using. Since I currently have some WiFi issues, I would like to know which account I'm using. How can I know that?

Note that when I go to the WiFi settings for the eduroam network, such information is not present, even after tapping on "View more". I don't see a way to get a QR code either.

Comment: Based on a quick search about eduroam, looks like it is using a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) for authentication?

Comment: @AndrewT. No, it does not use a captive portal (and this is not needed since this is not open wifi and authentication is done via PEAP/WPA-EAP/MSCHAPV2).